# Screen width issue on full page scroll effect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I'm working on a full page scroll effect, everything works almost perfectly except for a couple things:

1. Adding the `container` class to my `<div>` blocks with screens (`<section>`) breaks the screen width, not quite sure what this could be related to, the default style values of the `container` class or my styles for each component inside (`<section>`)?
2. Also there is a question about the footer and navbar, they are not included in `<section>` and in the `container` class, but they affect the scrolling, for example, when I scroll to the last screen and get to the footer, it stays on the screen and I can scroll the other screens while seeing the footer, and only when I scroll up with the cursor on the footer - it goes up and everything scrolls normally, how can I fix it?

You can see the error here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/auto-scroll-page-l3h36m?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00082863g1ez3yql%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00032863awf7infs%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00052863gxtpp4zn%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00072863cr91z3vx%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cln3cch8o00032863awf7infs%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00032863awf7infs%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohiellt01p52865kojzqrby%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fglobals.css%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohiellt01p52865kojzqrby%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fpage.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3ccpnp005a28636mmmn86o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Flayout.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln4qq0i502cs28649qcts4qm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252Fnavbar%252FNavbar.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln4ofngz003n286473tfdddz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fcomponents%252FFooter.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohiaoaw00qt28652p7q5g7y%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cln3cch8p00072863cr91z3vx%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00072863cr91z3vx%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln4r9o9q008e2864wgaokcxy%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cln4r9o9q008e2864wgaokcxy%2522%257D%252C%2522cln3cch8p00052863gxtpp4zn%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8p00052863gxtpp4zn%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00042863nxyzxagj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cln3cch8o00042863nxyzxagj%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

`page.tsx` :

```
"use client";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <section className="w-full lg:h-[1080px] md:h-[900px] sm:h-[1044px] xs:h-[812px] bg-[#3E3E3E] flex justify-center items-center text-4xl">
        first screen
      </section>
      <section className="w-full lg:h-[1080px] md:h-[900px] sm:h-[1044px] xs:h-[812px] bg-white flex justify-center items-center text-4xl">
        second screen
      </section>
      <section className="w-full lg:h-[1080px] md:h-[900px] sm:h-[1044px] xs:h-[812px] bg-white flex justify-center items-center text-4xl">
        third screen
      </section>
      <section className="w-full lg:h-[1080px] md:h-[900px] sm:h-[1044px] xs:h-[812px] bg-white flex justify-center items-center text-4xl">
        fourth screen
      </section>
      <section className="w-full lg:h-[1080px] md:h-[900px] sm:h-[1044px] xs:h-[812px] bg-white flex justify-center items-center text-4xl">
        fifth screen
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`globals.css` :

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem is that the `container` class is used from the tailwindcss library, and by disabling it in `tailwind.config.js` the screen width problem went away, however maybe there are more ways here how this can be solved?

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  corePlugins:
    container: false,
  },
};
```